# Share Data Using HTTP / FTP?

Tags: python, linux, networking

I have a network of `20 machines`, running Ubuntu 10.04.

Each machine has about 200[GB] of data that I'd like to share with all other `19 machines` for **READ ONLY PURPOSES**. The reading should be done at the fastest possible way.

A friend told me to look into setting up HTTP / FTP. Is it indeed the optimal way to share data between the machines (better than NFS)? if so, how do I go about it?

Is there a `python` module that would help in accessing/reading the data?

**UPDATE**: Just to clarify, all I want is to be able (from within machine `X`) to access one of machine `Y`s files and LOAD IT INTO MEMORY. all of the files are of uniform size (500 [KB]). Which method is fastest (SAMBA / NFS / HTTP / FTP)?

Comment: @user540009, "Each machine has about 200[GB] of data that I'd like to share with all other 19 machines for READ ONLY PURPOSES." sounds like you have 200GB/machine. Perhaps you can change your question to reflect only 500KB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hundreds of ways to solve this problem. You can mount a FTP, or HTTP file system over fuse, or even use NFS (why not?). Search for httpfs2 or curlftpfs (or even sshfs, which should not be used if you are looking for performance)

But the problem I see is, you have a single point of failure of the one and only master machine. Why not distribute the storage?

I usually using glusterfs [1], which is fast and can be used in different modes.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_file_system

Answer (score 2):

With `python` you can start up a webserver via a simple one-liner in the directory where the data is stored.

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Edit:

It creates a simple web server on port 8000, performance wise I cannot tell you much, and for that type of questions it would be better to ask in SuperUser and not SO.

It doesn't autostart, but it wouldn't be hard to make it.

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate more? how do I access it? does it remain permanent even after the computer reboots? performance vs. NFS?

Comment: Updated my response.

Comment: WOW, never knew about it! Awesome!!!! +1

Comment: @user540009 You can put this command in your .bashrc, so when your machine boots you, the server will startup automatically.

Comment: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` might be suitable as one time thing, no more.

Comment: @zengr: `.bashrc` is not a place to start services

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian That's a simple way, which I generally use on my local machine. What are the other ways? Would love to know.

Comment: I'd consider setting up NGINX for this kind of setup, instead of `SimpleHTTPServer`.  It's known to be fast for static file access and super easy to install and configure.  Once you have one configuration file setup, you can just copy it to the other machines (supposing they all store files at the same absolute path).

Comment: @Andre: is `NGINX` faster / better than `NFS`?

Comment: @zengr: an existing service will take care about it for you. You don't need to worry about it unless you're writing your own service; in this case SysV init-scripts or [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) jobs could be used on Ubuntu.